# How to set a starting date in Jquery datetimepicker taken from a query using coldfusion?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I need to set a starting date in datetimepicker. how can i do that ? I checked with minDate and StartDate. But i couldn't able to set the starting date. Please give me a propper solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Sample Code :

```
StartDate = new Date("March 20, 2014");
jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({step:30});
jQuery('.datetimepicker_notime').datetimepicker({
        timepicker:false,
        format:'m/d/Y',
        minDate : StartDate,
        step:30
});
```

Comment: Does this code with the hard coded value function properly?

Comment: Thank you Guys.. I solve this with following..

<cfset datediff = dateDiff("d", qry.startDate, now())>
<cfset startDate = dateFormat(dateAdd("d", datediff, "1970/01/01"), "YYYY/MM/DD")>

jQuery('#filterStartDate').datetimepicker({
 timepicker:false,
 format:'m/d/Y',
 minDate:'-<cfoutput>#startDate#</cfoutput>'
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs for this jQuery plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) (if this is the one that you are using) the start date can be set like this:

> Date Time Picker start date #
>
> javaScript
>
> ```
> jQuery('#datetimepicker_start_time').datetimepicker({
>     startDate:'1971/05/01'
> });
> ```
>
> startDate - if input value is empty, calendar set date from this starDate
>
> examples:
>
> ```
> {startDate:'1987/12/03'}
> {startDate:new Date()}
> {startDate:'+1970/01/02'} // tomorrow
> {startDate:'08.12.1986',formatDate:'d.m.Y'}
> ```

Adding this to your example it would look like this:

```
StartDate = '2014/03/20';
jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({step:30});
jQuery('.datetimepicker_notime').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'m/d/Y',
    startDate: StartDate,
    step:30
});
```

Comment: Thank you Guys.. I solve this with following..

<cfset datediff = dateDiff("d", qry.startDate, now())>
<cfset startDate = dateFormat(dateAdd("d", datediff, "1970/01/01"), "YYYY/MM/DD")>

jQuery('#filterStartDate').datetimepicker({
 timepicker:false,
 format:'m/d/Y',
 minDate:'-<cfoutput>#startDate#</cfoutput>'
});

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
defaultDate : 'your date here',
minDate : 0
```

Comment: Thank you Guys.. I solve this with following..

<cfset datediff = dateDiff("d", qry.startDate, now())>
<cfset startDate = dateFormat(dateAdd("d", datediff, "1970/01/01"), "YYYY/MM/DD")>

jQuery('#filterStartDate').datetimepicker({
 timepicker:false,
 format:'m/d/Y',
 minDate:'-<cfoutput>#startDate#</cfoutput>'
});

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys.. I solve this with following.. Now Its working fine for me.

```
<cfset datediff = dateDiff("d", qry.startDate, now())>
<cfset startDate = dateFormat(dateAdd("d", datediff, "1970/01/01"), "YYYY/MM/DD")>

jQuery('#filterStartDate').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'m/d/Y',
    minDate:'-<cfoutput>#startDate#</cfoutput>'
});
```