# How to disable previous date on edit using datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datetimepicker

I am using date time picker.on edit page the selected value is not displaying. 
when I check the code element, I am seeing the result in value attribute.
my code is

```
  $('#id').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    minDate:moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    useCurrent: false
  });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#id').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    minDate: new Date(), // Or try minDate: 0
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    useCurrent: false
});
```

You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637843/6163727) too.

Comment: No luck with the above code.. I am getting the date pick but in edit I am able to select the previous dates .@aboelnour

Comment: try to work with this code only `$('#id').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date() // or minDate: 0
  });`

Comment: Great. Happy to help.